# Database not updating with MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli, crud

I'm beginner at PHP and I'm using a tutorial I found on the web to work a new piece of a new CMS I'm building. The problem is that the tutorial works just fine but when I start to alter it to my use it cannot connect to the database to update. I receive my error "Database Error: Unable to update record." I can add and delete but not update.

Index.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>MySQLi Tutorial</title>

    </head>
<body>

<?php
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

if($action=='delete'){ //if the user clicked ok, run our delete query

    $query = "DELETE FROM family WHERE fid = ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['fid'])."";
    if( $mysqli->query($query) ){
        echo "User was deleted.";
    }else{
        echo "Database Error: Unable to delete record.";
    }

}

$query = "SELECT * FROM family";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

$num_results = $result->num_rows;

echo "<div><a href='add.php'>Create New Record</a></div>";

if( $num_results ){

    echo "<table border='1'>";//start table
    //creating our table heading
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>name</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    //loop to show each records
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            //extract row
            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
            //just $firstname only
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<a href='edit.php?fid={$fid}'>Edit</a>";
                    echo " / ";
                    echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$fid} );'>Delete</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";//end table

}else{
    //if table is empty
    echo "No records found.";
}

//disconnect from database
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function delete_user( fid ){
        //this script helps us to

        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok
            //redirect to url with action as delete and fid to the record to be deleted
            window.location = 'index.php?action=delete&fid=' + fid;
        } 
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

add.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MySQLi Create Record</title>

    </head>
<body>
<!--we have our html form here where user information will be entered-->
<form action='#' method='post' border='0'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Firstname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name' /></td>
        </tr>

            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='hidden' name='action' value='create' />
                <input type='submit' value='Save' />

                <a href='index.php'>Back to index</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

if($action=='create'){
    //include database connection
    include 'db_connect.php';

    //write query
    $query = "insert into family 
                set
                name = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']) ."'
                    ";

    if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
        echo "User was created.";
    }else{
        echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>



</body>
</html>
```

edit.php

```
<?php
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update"){
    //write query
    $query = "update users 
                set
                    name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."', 
                    where 
                    fid='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fid'])."'";

    if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
        echo "User was updated.";
    }else{
        echo "Database Error: Unable to update record.";
    }
}

$query = "select fid, name 
            from family
            where fid='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fid'])."'
            limit 0,1";

$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$fid = $row['fid'];
$name = $row['name'];
?>
<!--we have our html form here where new user information will be entered-->
<form action='#' method='post' border='0'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Firstname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo $name;  ?>' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <!-- so that we could identify what record is to be updated -->
                <input type='hidden' name='fid' value='<?php echo $fid ?>' /> 

                <!-- we will set the action to edit -->
                <input type='hidden' name='action' value='update' />
                <input type='submit' value='Edit' />

                <a href='index.php'>Back to index</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

> > >

I have been unable to find the proper language to fix this but I believe it's because I"m using some form of multiples but I am not familiar with the mysqli/php languages to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: check to see if the DB user account you are using to connect to MySQL has privileges to perform UPDATE

Comment: It does as the original tutorial files can add, edit and delete.

Comment: it looks like your sql script has a typo.  There is a comma at the end of this line name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',  Also make sure there is a space before and after the WHERE statement.  Also your fid value at the end of your sql script is in single quotes.  Check the data type for the fid column.  If it is varchar or char etc, you should be good but if it is of type int or something similar, there should be no single quotes around the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the comma at the end of:

`name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',`

the query should be:

```
$query = "update users 
            set
                name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'
                where 
                fid='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['fid'])."'";
```